# Crystal Reports - SECTION NAME - Is there a way to conditionally check or store the SECTION NAME in a within formula field

Tags: crystal-reports

I would like to check in which section the formula is in and then conditionally return a specific value (either a database value or a calculated value) from the associated detail line data.   Trying to avoid having to setup a separate formula for each detail section.

I tried setting up a loop counter but the loop counter never changes for same sections (details a, b, c, d, etc) only when the record number changes.  I setup a Whileprinting formula (Init & Calc) without success

- Header section - Global Numbervar N:=0;
- Detail section - WhilePrintingRecords; Numbervar N; Global NumberVar N:=N+1

Again would like to setup a single formula that would return a different value based on which section its is in.

Formula would be something like...

"section Name" = Details a, Details b, Details c, or Page Header a, Page Header b, etc

`If "Section Name" = "Details a" then
     \\ Return Value 1
      {NETSALES_TODAY}
Else if "Section Name" = "Details b" then
     \\ Return Value 2
      {NETSALES_MTD}
Else if "Section Name" = "Details c" then
     \\ Return Value 3
      {NETSALES_QTD}
Else {NETSALES_YTD}`

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: IT SEEMS IT DID NOT WORK - It is kept here for historical reasons (and because knowing it does not work is still valuable).

---

I think you were very close. I can't test it right now, but give it a try:

1. Create a formula like you did. Let's call it {@Declaration}.

```
global numbervar N := 0;
```

2. Create another formula like you did. Let's call it {@Increment}.

```
global numbervar N;
N := N + 1;
```

3. Put {@Declaration} in the report header.
4. Put the {@Increment} **in the three detail sections**.
5. Modify your formula to check the value of N mod 4 to be 0, 1, 2 or 3. Maybe you don't need the mod (just in case of many details rows).

```
  global numbervar N;
  if N mod 3 = 0 then {NETSALES_TODAY}
  else if N mod 3 = 1 then {NETSALES_MTD}
  else if N mod 3 = 2 then {NETSALES_QTD}
  else {NETSALES_YTD}
```

The purposed differences are (1) put the formula 3 times and (2) a small correction in the formula itself.

Comment: I tested your answer/response.  Thanks for trying but the increment formula does NOT get a +1 for each detail section.  I have not found any documentation or examples via my online searches that says one way or the other that this will work.

Comment: I may re-post my question to this site and concentrate on seeing if there is a way to identify which section the formula is in. i.e.,  if "Section Name" = "Details c"